# Passing method as parameter in blazor

Tags: c#, inheritance, blazor

I'm passing a method from a parent Blazor component into a child.

The parent definition looks like:

```
public bool AddOrUpdate(MyModel myModel)
{ 
    // do stuff
        
    return true;
}
```

In the `ChildComponent.razor.cs` it looks like:

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<MyModel> SaveMethod { get; set; }
```

And it's passed into the child from the parent like:

```
<ChildComponent SaveMethod="@AddOrUpdate" />
```

When I call the method in the child using

```
SaveMethod(newNote);
```

it throws:

`Non invocable member cannot be used like a method`

What's the issue?

EDIT: using `invoke` worked to get me past the initial error, but now I'm seeing `CS1503    Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'EventCallback'`

Comment: `SaveMethod` is a property, not a method; you therefore cannot invoke it as a method.  You could try it without the `{ get; set; }` and see what happens.

Comment: Or use something like `SaveMethod.Invoke()`.  Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?view=net-6.0) for examples on correct usage.

Comment: Have a look at the source code https://source.dot.net/#q=Virtualize the ItemsProvider parameter is a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

`SaveMethod` is a property. You should instead use `SaveMethod.InvokeAsync(newNote);` (and add `await` if you're inside of asynchronous method).

Read more about event callbacks [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#eventcallback).

Comment: Thanks, @KifoPL -- however, now I'm seeing a different error

Comment: try `<ChildComponent SaveMethod="@(model => AddOrUpdate(model))"/>`

Answer (score 0):

This is not rocket science.  Match the EventCalback method pattern to the assigned method and it works.

Here's a full working version of Enet's answer:

The model.

```
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
```

The component

```
<button @onclick="SaveModel">Save</button>

@code {
    private MyModel _myModel => new MyModel() { Name= $"clicked at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}" };

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<MyModel> SaveMethod { get; set; } 

    private void SaveModel()
    {
        // Invoke the parent's AddOrUpdate, passing it an instance of 
        // MyModel 
        SaveMethod.InvokeAsync(_myModel);
    } 
}
```

And Index page demo

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<MyComponent SaveMethod="this.AddOrUpdate" />

<div class="p-2">
    @model.Name
</div>

@code {
    MyModel model = new MyModel();

    public void AddOrUpdate(MyModel myModel)
    {
        model = myModel;
    }
}
```